# What does "let’s get rocks" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

I saw this on a t-shirt one of my friends is about to make for a sports event.

> Let’s get rock (or "rocks", I am not sure).

And there is a dirt bike on it too.

The event is dirt bike racing, my friend is Hungarian just like me and he does not speak English well. Therefore I don't think it is figurative or a word play. My worry is that it is a mistake. That is why I wanted to ask native speakers after having browsed the internet to find something similar.

What does "let’s get rocks" mean? It does not sound right to me. Any thoughts on it?

Comment: Where was the shirt bought? It's pretty common for foreign companies to put nonsense English phrases (and for American companies to put nonsense phrases from other languages) on shirts.

Comment: That is the thing. My friend got a company to design and make it. But i dont know yet who’s idea the text was.

Comment: "Let's Rock" is a common expression encouraging people to do something exciting. "Let's get rock" is the kind of nonsense people write on a tee shirt when they don't speak English well.

Comment: It should be: Let's get our rocks off. :) As is, it's gibberish. Typically, riding a dirt bike is a way to get your rocks  off. I'll let you look that up. That sounds dirty the way it should. Get it? Dirt bikes, dirty?

Answer (score 1):

Your friend's expression

> **Let's get rocks**

is a little nonsensical in relation to dirt bikes, unless it was possibly

> Let's get Rocks

Since *Behind the Rocks* or possibly *Hartman Rocks* are a well know group of dirt bike trails, but that would make it more site specific.

A possible alternative your friend might have meant is

> Let's get rocking

which has the same meaning as

> Let's rock

which means *to get going and participate* in an event.

Unless he really meant a reference to an alternative lifestyle in which

> Let's get rocks

has the slang meaning of

> Let's get drugs